# How can I view Google My Maps on my phone (Nexus One)?

Tags: google-maps

I have a collection of locations in `Google My Maps` but I don't know how to access it from my phone. Using the browser and go to google map site doesn't help at all. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bearing in mind I'm using CyanogenMod6 + Google Apps your mileage may vary - but I can access my My Maps as follows:

- Open Google Maps (the application, not the full site)
- Click menu
- Select Layers
- Select More Layers
- Select My Maps and your maps should be displayed

Job done

[Edit] Looks like I'd installed the wrong Google Apps package when I flash my ROM last night, (tiny instead of medium), and the updated version has the Layers button up next to the search bar - so I don't need to open the menu (step 2) anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the official 'Google Maps' app to view your collections. If you click on the 'Pin' next to the search box to bring up the Places screen, then press 'Menu', you'll see an option for 'My Maps' so you can access any of your previously created collections.

Google Maps app -> Pin Button (next to search box) -> Menu Key -> 'My Maps'

[Link to Google Maps just in case you don't have it installed](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps)

(Alternatively, you can skip a couple of steps by opening Google Maps using the 'Places' shortcut, which takes you directly to the Places screen, from where you can press the Menu button, then select 'My Maps')