# how to view custom google map on my android device?

Tags: google-maps

I have created a new map (layer) using the website google-map-engine.

how can I view this custom map on my android device?

It used to use google-map web site and then view on mobile via official app

but now i don't find the way to view. Is it not accessible anymore?

Does someone know how to show saved maps in the official `google maps` app?

Comment: I think we're going to need some more information in order to help you.

Comment: like what? I'll be happy to provide

Comment: Is [the official app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b) not working for you? What have you attempted, specifically, and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: It used to use google-map web site and then view on mobile via official app

but now i don't find the way to view. Is it not accessible anymore?

Does someone know how to show saved maps in the official google maps app?

Comment: Did you save it to "My Maps"? If so, see: [How can I view Google My Maps on my phone (Nexus One)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6169)

Comment: but that's the thing there used to be a "show layers" but I don't see it under the menu anymore